# Why I got an empty struct after json.Unmarshal()?

Tags: go

coders. I'm completely newbie to Go and got a little bit confused about json.Unmarshal output:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := `[{"First":"James","Last":"Bond","Age":32,"Sayings":["Shaken, not stirred","Youth is no guarantee of innovation","In his majesty's royal service"]},{"First":"Miss","Last":"Moneypenny","Age":27,"Sayings":["James, it is soo good to see you","Would you like me to take care of that for you, James?","I would really prefer to be a secret agent myself."]},{"First":"M","Last":"Hmmmm","Age":54,"Sayings":["Oh, James. You didn't.","Dear God, what has James done now?","Can someone please tell me where James Bond is?"]}]`

    var res []struct{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &res)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Output:

```
[{} {} {}]
```

Why is it empty? 
You can try it here: https://play.golang.org/p/yztOLJADIXx

Comment: Because `res` is a slice of empty structs, there's nothing to unmarshal into. This is not how unmarshaling works. Maybe try the [tour](https://tour.golang.org/) or [go by example](https://gobyexample.com/json) to learn more.

Comment: `struct{}` != `arbitrary object`.

Comment: Why is this question closed because of typos? This person is new to go and may not fully understand how everything works yet. It's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to unmarshal JSON objects without knowing their fields, use a `map[string]interface{}`:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := `[{"First":"James","Last":"Bond","Age":32,"Sayings":["Shaken, not stirred","Youth is no guarantee of innovation","In his majesty's royal service"]},{"First":"Miss","Last":"Moneypenny","Age":27,"Sayings":["James, it is soo good to see you","Would you like me to take care of that for you, James?","I would really prefer to be a secret agent myself."]},{"First":"M","Last":"Hmmmm","Age":54,"Sayings":["Oh, James. You didn't.","Dear God, what has James done now?","Can someone please tell me where James Bond is?"]}]`

    var res []map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &res)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Try it here: https://play.golang.org/p/iPlBgguE8Kk

However, if you know the names of the fields you're going to unmarshal, you should define the structure. In your case it would look like that:

```
type Person struct {
    First   string   `json:"First"`
    Last    string   `json:"Last"`
    Age     int      `json:"Age"`
    Sayings []string `json:"Sayings"`
}
```

Try this solution here: https://play.golang.org/p/jCrCteYTaIf